# JavaScript - How to sort an array of array by number strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, lodash

I receive an array like this:

```
[
    [{"name":"one","team":"------","checked":false,"position":"-"},
     {"name":"two","team":"------","checked":false,"position":"1"}],
    [{"name":"three","team":"------","checked":false,"position":"3"},
     {"name":"four","team":"------","checked":false,"position":"7"}]
]
```

I want the final output to be like this:

```
[
    [{"name":"two","team":"------","checked":false,"position":"1"},
     {"name":"four","team":"------","checked":false,"position":"7"}],
    [{"name":"three","team":"------","checked":false,"position":"3"},
     {"name":"one","team":"------","checked":false,"position":"-"}]
]
```

That means that the array is sorted by the greatest position value and the least position value in the first sub-array, then the second greatest position value and the second least position value in the second sub-array. If there is a "-" in position it is left after the string numbers.

So far I have tried this with lodash:

```
var mergedArray = vm.roundOf4[0].concat(vm.roundOf4[1]);
var count = _.countBy(mergedArray, {position: '-'});

var ascArray = _.cloneDeep(mergedArray);
var descArray = _.cloneDeep(mergedArray);

_.sortByOrder(ascArray, 'position', 'asc');
_.sortByOrder(descArray, 'position', 'desc');

_.times(count.true, ascArray.push(ascArray.shift()));

vm.roundOf4.some(function (array, i) {
    array.some(function (object, j) {

        if (j === 0) {
            vm.roundOf4[i][j] = ascArray[i];

        } else if (j === 1) {
            vm.roundOf4[i][j] = descArray[i];
        }

    });
});
```

But the ascending sort by function is not sorting correctly the position value, so it's giving random sorting. I don't know if it is because position is a string value.

Should I use numbers instead?

Comment: `1` and `-` were in the same sub-array but in your desired output they're separated. What is the logic behind that?

Comment: There's no logic, just "-" isn't set yet. It can be another number, but because it isn't set yet it is left at the end, the same applies for whatever object.

Comment: Not talking about `-`, I'm talking about how `1` and `-` got separated from each other after the sort! (**before:** they were in the same sub-array, **after:** each one went to a different sub-array)! Same for `7` and `3`!

Comment: And `1`, `7`, `3` and `-` don't look sorted to me!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The array is sorted by the greatest position value and the least position value in the first array, then the second greatest position value and the second least position value in the second array. The position with "-" is left after the string numbers.

Comment: so for four values, it might go with just reassigning the objects, but what should happen with more?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// get an array of object an return the min index or the max index depending on the parameter max (true => max index, false => min index)
function minMax(arr, max) {
  var index = 0;                                             // assuming the index 0 is the min or max
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {                     // for each other object in the array
    if(arr[index].position == '-')                           // if the position of the object at index index is '-' then assume the index is this i (before starting the comparison, find an item which have a number for its position property)
      index = i;
    else if ((arr[i].position > arr[index].position) == max) // now that the object at index index has a valid position property, make the comparison depending on the argument max
      index = i;
  }
  return index;
}

// take an two dimensional array and rearrange it
function reArrange(arr) {
  var simple = arr.reduce(function(acc, a) {                 // first let's make the two dimensional array into a one dimensional array
    return acc.concat(a);
  }, []);
  
  var result = [];                                           // the result array
  while(simple.length) {                                     // while there is element in the one dimensional array
    var min = minMax(simple, false);                         // get the min index
    var max = minMax(simple, true);                          // get the max
    result.push([                                            // push the items at the min and max indexes as a sub-array of the result array
      simple.splice(min, 1)[0],                              // splice to remove it from simple array as well
      simple.splice((max < min)? max: max - 1, 1)[0]         // if max index is after min index then substract one because the above splice shrank the array 
    ]);
  }
  return result;
}



var arr = [
    [{"name":"one","team":"------","checked":false,"position":"-"},
     {"name":"two","team":"------","checked":false,"position":"1"}],
    [{"name":"three","team":"------","checked":false,"position":"3"},
     {"name":"four","team":"------","checked":false,"position":"7"}]
];

console.log(reArrange(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sort the inner array, then assign to result and sort again.

```js
var data = [[{ "name": "one", "team": "------", "checked": false, "position": "-" }, { "name": "two", "team": "------", "checked": false, "position": "1" }], [{ "name": "three", "team": "------", "checked": false, "position": "3" }, { "name": "four", "team": "------", "checked": false, "position": "7" }]],
    result = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    a.sort(function (a, b) { return (+b.position || Number.MIN_VALUE) - (+a.position || Number.MIN_VALUE); });
});

data.forEach(function (a, i) {
    a.forEach(function (b, j) {
        result[j] = result[j] || [];
        result[j][i] = b;
    });
});

result.forEach(function (a) {
    a.sort(function (a, b) { return (+a.position || Number.MAX_VALUE) - (+b.position || Number.MAX_VALUE); });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```